# gevent using Queue get and socket recv at the same time

Tags: python, gevent

as the title mentioned

example code:

```
import gevent
from gevent.queue import Queue

class Worker(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.sock = sock
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def _run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            msg_from_queue = self.queue.get()    # block call
            msg_from_sock = self.sock.recv(128)  # block call

worker = Worker(sock)
worker.start()
```

I wanna worker handle two events:

1. message recv from sock
2. message get from queue

but the two are all block calls

How should I do, to let worker get from sock and queue at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:

```
class Worker(gevent.Greenlet):
    def _sock_recv(self):
        # ...
    def _queue_get(self):
        # ...
    def _run(self):
        recv = gevent.spawn(self._sock_recv)
        get = gevent.spawn(self._queue_get)
        gevent.joinall([recv, get])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Splitting `Worker` into two workers?

```
class QueueWorker(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        super(QueueWorker, self).__init__()

    def _run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            msg = self.queue.get()    # block call
            print 'queue:', msg


class SocketWorker(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.sock = sock
        super(SocketWorker, self).__init__()

    def _run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            msg = self.sock.recv(128)  # block call
            print 'socket:', msg

worker1 = QueueWorker(queue)
worker1.start()
worker2 = SocketWorker(sock)
worker2.start()
```

Comment: Hi, Look below, I found a way for this.  But still thanks for helping

Comment: @Yueyoum, `gevent.joinall()` waits for all jobs to complete. Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure. gevent.joinall() only waits this worker's sub jobs, not the whole program process, right?   In a test , I create three/four workers, It's working fine now.

Comment: `gevnet.joinall([recv, get])` wait for `recv`, `get` **both** to complete, not the whole program process.

Comment: yes, this what I wanted, `joinall([recv, get])` to let the two greenlet run, and `recv` complete before `get`. So, there additional codes in my project: `def clear(*args): get.kill(); recv.link(clear)`.So , when `rece` completed , then kill `get` greenlate, finally, this worker exit automatically

Comment: I misunderstood. Maybe while loops are inside _sock_recv, _queue_get?